# Display Modifications Each Time an Item is Updated

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, custom-list

Not sure if this can be accomplished, but I want to try.

Objective: When an item is modified SharePoint keeps track of the modification date, time, and person who modified the item.  You can see this when you view the item.  But it only shows the last modified data not all.  So if the item was updated 5 times it only shows the 5th modification data because it was the last time it was modified.

Question: Is there a way to show each time a item is modified than just showing the most recent?  It doesn't have to appear in the view item. If is easier it can appear in another column on the same line item row?

Research: I found a couple suggestions to create a workflow and update the line item. But what am I updating the item with?  another way I found was using a .NET framework.  Another way was to use the versioning history. But how would I connect the versioning history to each line.  So that may not work.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: You add an extra Field where your workflow adds each Modified event to

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with the data. Versioning is definitely the way to collect the info. There are multiple ways to access that version history.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson Thank you.  You said there are multiple ways to access version history?  Can you share some of those ways?  I only know of one way.

Comment: You can use REST or SOAP calls to get at the version history.